# how to access child element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access all the subelelements of a given element . For ex :

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="1">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
  </div>
  <span></span>
  <div></div>      
 </div>
```

Like in abover structure `#main` contains 5 elements ( 2 div and 3 span ). How can i access it all in a single query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use universal selector.

```
$('#main *')
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a wildcard selector, like this:

```
$("#main *")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('#main').find('*');
```